# "¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una lista enlazada y un arreglo en términos de estructuras de datos?

Tags: javascript, array, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy estudiando estructuras de datos y me gustaría entender mejor la diferencia entre una lista enlazada y un arreglo. He leído sobre ambos conceptos, pero aún no tengo claro cuáles son las diferencias clave en términos de implementación y uso en programas.

Comment: he quitado la etiqueta javascript ya que tu pregunta no tiene nada de código en javascript

Comment: Yo la he vuelto a agregar porque la etiqueta es totalmente necesaria para responder la pregunta. No es lo mismo un array en javascript que en C++

Comment: @Yussef pq no es lo mismo?

Comment: @Japv Porque uno tiene dimensión dinámica y el otro no, porque uno en js puedes almacenar distintos tipos de datos y en otros lenguajes no, esto es importante porque la asignación de memoria funciona distinta. El índice que es una característica importante del array, en algunos lenguajes comienza en 1 no en cero.

Comment: Array en ciencias de la computación tiene una definición de lo más abstracta (y en mi opinión bastante poco útil), la cosa cambia cuando se habla en términos de "tipo de dato" (que la mayoría de lenguaje de alto nivel lo incluyen), pero cada lenguaje lo implementa diferente. Y es el OP el que enmarca su pregunta en javascript por lo que la respuesta debe considerar no la definición abstracta si no la implementación particular en JS. Al quitar la etiqueta cambia sustancialmente la pregunta

Comment: existe una lista enlazada en js??? cual seria la implementacion? Ximena estas segura que estas estudiando estos tipos de datos en js?

Answer (score 0):

Un arreglo es una lista de elementos contiguos en memoria. Su tamaño puede ser fijo o variable.

En una lista enlazada, cada elemento posee una referencia al siguiente y no necesariamente son contiguos en memoria.

Para insertar y eliminar elementos constantemente, una lista enlazada sería lo mejor. Si vas a cargar los elementos una sola vez o es más importante el acceso aleatorio inmediato, elije un arreglo.

---

### Comparación

Podemos analizar algunos aspectos como el tiempo de acceso, el tiempo de inserción y la cantidad de memoria que usan.

#### Arreglo

- El **tiempo de acceso** es muy **pequeño**.
- La **inserción** es más **lenta**. Para insertar un elemento es necesario hacer lugar y desplazar los demás elementos. Además, si el tamaño varía, cada vez que se queda sin espacio se copia su contenido a otra región de memoria más grande.
- Son **compactos** así que hacen un uso eficiente de la memoria.
- Todas estas propiedades se deben a la naturaleza de la estructura: todos los elementos son contiguos en memoria.

#### Lista enlazada

- El **acceso** es más **lento** ya que es necesario acceder a todos los elementos anteriores.
- La **inserción** es **rápida**. Lo único que hay que hacer es crear un elemento más y modificar algunas referencias.
- Consumen más memoria ya que además del dato, deben contener una referencia al siguiente elemento; y si se trata de una lista doblemente enlazada, también el anterior.

---

### Implementación

En la mayoría de lenguajes es fácil crear un arreglo. En Javascript puedes crearlo mediante [literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals), el [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) o [métodos estáticos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#static_methods).

```
let arreglo = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
let arreglo2 = new Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Javascript no cuenta con una estructura de lista enlazada. Una posible implementación es la siguiente:

```js
const nodo = {
    valor: null,
    siguiente: null
};

class Lista {
    constructor(){
        this.primero = null
        this.ultimo = null
    }

    agregar(valor) {
        let nuevo = Object.create(nodo);
        nuevo.valor = valor;
        if (this.primero)
            this.ultimo.siguiente = nuevo;
        else
            this.primero = this.ultimo = nuevo;    
    }

    imprimir(){
        let nodo = this.primero
        while (nodo){
            console.log(nodo.valor)
            nodo = nodo.siguiente
        }
    }
}

let lista1 = new Lista()
lista1.agregar(1)
lista1.agregar(2)
lista1.imprimir()
```